# ngAnimate flexbox transition

Tags: html, css, flexbox, ng-animate

How to animate first input field transition to the center of a flexbox container? Second and third inputs fade in/out, but the first one changes position instantly. Is there anyway to apply animation to the first input?.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 800px;
  background-color: red;
  justify-content: center;
}

.fade-element-in.ng-enter {
  transition: 0.8s linear all;
  opacity: 0;
}

.fade-element-in-init .fade-element-in.ng-enter {
  opacity: 1;
}

.fade-element-in.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.fade-element-in.ng-leave {
  transition: 0.3s linear all;
  opacity: 1;
}

.fade-element-in.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl" ng-init="shown='true'">
  <div class="container">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" class="fade-element-in" ng-if="!shown" />
    <input type="text" class="fade-element-in" ng-if="!shown" />
    <button ng-click="shown=!shown">{{shown}}</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/cpcb4wen/

Comment: Should it also fade, or slide or...? And when? ... on page load?, or while second/third is fading in?, or while they fading out? ...

Comment: When it is changing its position, so after second and third fades in/out it should move to the center/left accordingly  with animation